# For which values ​​of $z$ the inequality $|e^{z-1}|<2$ holds

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to find for which values of $z$ the following inquality holds
$$|e^{z-1}|<2$$
what I tried to do is:
$$|e^{z-1}|=|e^{x-1+y\mathbb{i}}|<2$$
$$=e^{x-1}\cdot(\cos(y)
+ \mathbb{i} \sin(y))$$
OR another thing I tried:
$$z-1=\ln(2) \rightarrow z<\ln(2)+1$$
what is right? and how to continue?
thanks.

Comment: Not $\;z\;$ but **the real part** of $\;z\;$ in the last line!

Comment: why is the real part? because I compare coefficients the coefficient of the Im will be zero ?

Comment: Well, yes: $$|e^{a+ib}|=|e^a|\,|e^{ib}|=e^a$$ since, and you by now should be able to prove this, whenever $\,b\in\Bbb R\implies \;|e^{bi}|=1\;$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ , then

$$|e^{z-1}|=|e^{x-1+iy}|=e^{x-1}<2\iff x-1<\log 2\iff x<\log 2 +1$$

and that's all!